# Emacs: hl-line-mode conflicts with highlight-phrase

Tags: emacs

I highlight current line by evaluating:

```
(hl-line-mode)
```

It could also be set globally:

```
(global-hl-line-mode nil)
```

The problem is that this way line highlighting overrides `highlight-phrase`. So my question is: "how to highlight both current line and a given phrase in this line?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `highlight-phrase` and `hl-line` apply faces that have a background color set. `hl-line` wins because it uses an overlay, and [overlays always override text properties, which  `highlight-phrase` uses](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Overlay-Properties.html#Overlay-Properties). I suggest that you work around this by customizing the `hi-yellow` face to use a bright foreground color instead of a background color, or even a box.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't inderstand what can be done to work around the problem, but at least I've got that hl-line wins because it uses overlay. Maybe I'll manage all that later. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The workaround I described is to modify the `hi-yellow` face (perhaps using `M-x customize-face`) in order to give it different face attributes that will allow it to be seen easily, even when `hl-line` overrides the `foreground`. (It's not a perfect solution, of course!)

Comment: Thanks a lot - I finally made it! Customizing "foreground" alone was not working though. One has turn off the "inherit" flag. I think I'll post the whole answer - for it'll be more convenient for others. Thanks again for Your help.

Comment: Glad you got it working. You should mark one of the 2 answers as accepted so that the question is closed. :-)

Answer (score 2):

So here's some, definetly not ideal, solution. Do:

```
M-x customize-face
```

emacs then asks you which one, and I did

```
hl-line
```

Then I turned off "inherit" flag (the last one), and turned on the "foreground" flag, - it was saying "black" - I made it red. After that You should save it all at the top of the page - either - for this seccion only, or for future sessions too.

That's it! This way current line text arrears of red font, while `highlight-phrase` highlights the phrase with yellow.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: The previous solution that I posted doesn't work, but this one should.**

Highlight has two modes, one for font-lock-enabled buffers (which uses font-lock) and one for without (which uses overlay).  The solution I found was to simply force highlight to use overlay at all times, and thus have higher priority over hl-line (because shorter overlays have an implicitly higher priority, given the same value of `priority`).

To do this I went into `hi-lock.el` and replaced every instance of `font-lock-fontified` with `nil`.  Be sure to `M-x byte-compile-file` afterwards in order to update `hi-lock.elc`.

Comment: That's cool. I don't highlight current line anymore, but if I'll do -- I'll probably use that solution.

Comment: @fzlogic i followed the steps exactly(modify hi-lock.el, byte compbile it), and still does not work, any stpes missing here? any lines to add into init.el? thanks!

Comment: @shelper I just (re-)tested it and it works fine.  Do you happen to have multiple versions of emacs installed?

Comment: @fzlogic no, i only using emacs 24.3. can you try to see if that works with the package idle-highlight? you can easily find it in the package list of emacs if you using v24.

Comment: Funny I tried this again on my home computer and it did not work (!).  Tested again on my office and it still worked, but only on my Emacs 23.  I think something got changed in 24.3 so this "fix" doesn't really work anymore.  Sorry!